# Hyperlink in moderncv with acrobat reader

Tags: hyperref, pdf, urls, moderncv

The `hyperref` in `moderncv` for urls and the email address cannot be opened with adobe acrobat reader. The links are working in other pdf readers. It's only an issue with `moderncv` opened in adobe acrobat reader. I tried to make a minimal example that shows the behavior. It is the same for `\href` and `\url`. Does anybody know a resolution?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}
\firstname{Test}
\familyname{Test}

\begin{document}

\cventry{2012}{test}{test}{\texttt{\href{http://www.google.com}{click me}}}{}{}
\cventry{2012}{test}{test}{\texttt{\url{http://www.google.com}}}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). You can also use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Works for me without problem.

Comment: You might check your security preferences in Acrobat Reader. In particular, the "Trust Manager" settings.

Comment: User "Patrick Xian" commented "Thanks, what @Null said works!".

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same issue with Adobe Acrobat 9 and Acrobat X Pro on two different computers. Strangely, I did not encounter an error using TeXstudio's internal PDF viewer -- the links work as is.

I started with this MWE based on the one in the question:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}
\firstname{Test}
\familyname{Test}

\begin{document}

\cventry{2012}{test}{test}{\texttt{\href{http://www.google.com}{http://www.google.com}}}{}{}

\end{document}
```

When attempting to click a link using Acrobat I receive the following error:

[image]

I found an alternate solution based on [an1234's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195264/61108): add `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{baseurl={}}}` in the preamble (you can also add other options like `colorlinks`). Acrobat no longer generates the error with the fixed MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}
\firstname{Test}
\familyname{Test}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{baseurl={}}}

\begin{document}

\cventry{2012}{test}{test}{\texttt{\href{http://www.google.com}{http://www.google.com}}}{}{}

\end{document}
```

I think this solution is preferable since you don't have to modify the moderncv.cls file.

Comment: Wow, this worked great without having to modify external files, thanks!

Comment: @JorgeGT Happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

On the `moderncv.cls` file I removed the `baseurl= http://` option under `\hypersetup` and it worked. I'm not sure why but it did.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I face exactly the same issue with Adobe Acrobat Reader 9.

The url works in other pdf readers, but not in adobe.

I think you gotta update the Adobe Acrobat Reader to a higher version (>10).