# Hyperlinks on moderncv not working Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: hyperref, moderncv, links, adobe

So, I know there's already a question about this ([Hyperlink in moderncv with acrobat reader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141054/hyperlink-in-moderncv-with-acrobat-reader/195076#195076)) but I have tried the solutions there (updating and security settings) and it still doesn't work and I don't think that it's an Adobe problem since I have other documents (not moderncv) where the links work perfectly.

I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro XI. The links do work on Preview.
Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\firstname{First name}
\familyname{Last name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Address line 1}{Address line 2}
\mobile{Phone}
\email{Email}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{colorlinks, urlcolor=NavyBlue}}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\cventry{Year}{Degree}{University}{Location}{GPA. \href{http://www.google.com}{Google}}{}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The link works without a problem for me (Ubuntu 12.04, Document Viewer 3.4.0). So I suppose it *is* an Adobe problem.

Comment: if it is an Adobe problem it is only when I work with moderncv and not with other type of tex documents.

Comment: BTW, I would use rather `https://www.google.com/` than `http://www.google.com`.

Answer (score 2):

On the moderncv.cls file I removed the baseurl= http:// option under hypersetup and it worked. I'm not sure why but it did.

Comment: But if `baseurl=` is set to `http://` already, can't you than just leave these out in your `\href` commands? Or change them to `https://` as Kurt says by using `hypersetup` in your file...